# Maximum Likelihood Estimate for Binomial Data

Tags: r, economics

I need to find the maximum likelihood estimate for a vector of binomial data.

one like this:

```
binvec <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.5)
```

I tried to first create the function and then optimize it with `optim()`.

```
llbinom <- function(theta, x) {return(sum(dbinom(x=x,
               size = theta[1],
               prob = theta[2],log=TRUE)))}
mybin <- optim(c(0.5,0.5),fn=llbinom,x=binvec)
mybin
```

I do get some result but also error messages that `NaN`s are being produced and the function cannot be evaluated at the initial parameters. I constructed it from an example that works for normally distributed data and believe I made a mistake in converting it.

Here, the original code I got:

```
ll <- function(theta,x) {return(-sum(dnorm(x=x,
   mean=theta[1],sd=theta[2],log=TRUE)))}
mle <- optim(c(5,3),fn=ll,x=binvec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues here.

- looks like you're missing a negative sign (`optim()` *minimizes* by default unless you set the control parameter `fnscale=-1`, so you need to define a *negative* log-likelihood function)
- the `size` parameter must be an integer
- it's unusual, and technically challenging, to to estimate the `size` parameter from data (this is  often done using *N-mixture models*, if you want to read up on the technique: e.g. see the `unmarked` package); usually the number of trials is assumed to be known. So I would try

```
llbinom <- function(theta, x) {return(
   -sum(dbinom(x=x,
               size = 1,
               prob = theta[1],log=TRUE)))}
mybin <- optim(c(0.5),fn=llbinom,x=binvec)
```

There are plenty of reasons to do this the Hard Way (numerically); if you really only need to find the MLE of the probability of a single binomial sample `x` (independent observations with the same probability of success out of `s` trials), the analytical solution is `sum(x)/sum(s)` ...

Comment: Thank you! That, definitely, makes more sense. When running the code R suggested using the Brent method (I added: method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1) do you reckon that makes sense in this context?

Comment: Yes.  Or fit the probability on the log-odds scale.